# How to search using a particular keyword in URL bar in PyQt5

Tags: python, browser, pyqt5

I'm a newbie in Python and I need help
So, I made a web browser using PyQt5 and it is running just fine.
But, I want to code as if we can type anything in the URL bar and it shows various links.
I will attach an image of the code and the browser

I did this by watching Programming Hero's video.
Please help me out.

Video Link : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z-5bZ8EoKu4

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
line_edit = QLineEdit()
complete_list = ['yahoo.com', 'google.com', 'google.co.uk'] #This will be the only strings used for the auto complete
completer = QCompleter(complete_list)
line_edit.setCompleter(completer)
```

You can also use QStandardItemModel instead of using a list